# Delete SQL row from an ID

Tags: php, delete-row

This syntax isn't working for me. I'm posting a variable from a html script, when echo'ed it will print the number.

However when I try to delete it via SQL it won't work.

```
<?php
$idholder = $_POST['delete_id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("hostaddress","username","pw","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM SWANK_support WHERE order='$idholder'");
mysqli_close($con);

header ("location: /support.php");
?>
```

Comment: Couple things. 1) what happens, is there any msql_error?  Also, you should at least validate $idholder, make certain it is an integer, for example, but if your id is supposed to be a varchar then do some other validation, and use prepared statements.

Comment: and the mysql error is?

Comment: It does not throw an error at all.

How should I go about validating it? By echoing it I have made sure that it is givign the correct value, which is an integer.

Comment: I removed the real database details from your question - you probably don't want to share those with the world.

Comment: Try using [MySQLi::$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get an error out of it.

Comment: Cheers Steve, Wow! I am beyond tired, lifesaver!

Comment: you dont check for errors in the delete querry, so of course you wont see them